# How can I change the title of a UIButton before all code in an IBAction is completed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a button that reloads data from an online database. I want the UIButton title to change from "Reset data" to "Reset pending..." immediately when the button is pressed; the data reload code to occur, and the `UIButton` title to change to "Reset complete" when the data reload completion fires.

I can't get the button title to change before everything under `@IBAction func` returns, and would very much appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

If I remove the `resetAllDataFromOnline()` line from `@IBAction` the title changes as expected, if not I only get the reset complete when the download completes. I also can't change a separate label on the page either.

```
@IBAction func resetDataFromOnlineButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    resetDataFromOnlineButton.setTitle("Reset pending...", for: .normal)
    resetAllDataFromOnline()
}

func resetAllDataFromOnline() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).sync {
        NetworkHelperFunctions.updateAnEmptyLocalDatabaseFromOnline(coreDataStack: self.coreDataStack) { (_) in
            let newCurrentUser = LoginHelpFunc.checkForValidUserAndLogoutIfNotValid(coreDataStack: self.coreDataStack)
            if let newCurrentUser = newCurrentUser {
                self.currentUser = newCurrentUser
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                resetDataFromOnlineButton.setTitle("Reset complete", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `sync` call in `resetAllDataFromOnline` prevents your action method from returning. Thus it can't return to the runloop and update the view of the button. You should try a `async` call instead. You should also call your update operations in the background to allow concurrent updates of the view:

```
func resetAllDataFromOnline() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        ...
    }
}
```